# Animating :before does not work properly

Tags: css, css-selectors, border, css-animations

**Problem**
I want to animate a ::before with css animations, but it keeps failing. Normally a animation would save the state of the animation when it's done (If I set it to forwards). However, this time it didn't. Any ideas why it does not work?

For some reason, it is also bugging... I want it to be a triangle top up, let it collapse an then be a triangle bottom up, so something like this:

**What should happen**
Begin:                   ▴
50% of animation: ─
End:                      ▾

A drawing of what it should look like (Changed the white to orange to make the difference visible in the image)
[image: Something like this]

**My Code**
My animation (See jsfiddle for the whole code)

```
@-webkit-keyframes animateEnvelope {
    0% {border-width: 0px 400px 200px 400px;}
    2% {border-color: transparent transparent #999 transparent;}
    50% {border-width: 200px 400px 100px 400px;}
    52% {border-color: transparent transparent #999 transparent}
    99% {border-color: #ECF0F1 transparent transparent transparent;}
} 

@keyframes animateEnvelope {
    0% {border-width: 0px 400px 200px 400px;}
    2% {border-color: transparent transparent #999 transparent;}
    50% {border-width: 200px 400px 100px 400px;}
    52% {border-color: transparent transparent #999 transparent}
    99% {border-color: #ECF0F1 transparent transparent transparent;}
}
```

[My JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hpcu7xny/)

I tried searching SO and Google, but no result turned up working for me.. You guys are my last hope

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/hpcu7xny/1/)?

Comment: @Harry somehow.. You see the grey triangle collapsing right? The bottom (well the widest part of the white triangle) should be alligned to the top of the base, I'll make a drawing to let you better understand it.

Comment: @Harry added a drawing to better explain what I would like to achieve

Comment: Is the `.base` always of a fixed width? If it is not then you shouldn't use `border` to generate this triangle.

Comment: @Harry yes it always has a fixed width. As I did not have much experience with shapes, I went for borders. Any ideas what I should use instead?

Comment: Generally using `clip-path` would be the better idea but the problem with that is the browser support. `border` is fine if it is fixed width. By the way, why is your `.base` so complex with very *specific* positioning values, very specific margins etc? These kind of make it very complex to achieve that triangle effect's positioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the image that you've posted the below should be the animation that you are looking for.

(*Please view the snippet in full screen mode as the base element has a lot of positioning which is not part of the answer*)

```css
body {
  background-color: pink;
}

.base {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #999;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0px 0 0 -285px;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-name: slideCardUp;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

@keyframes animateEnvelope {
  0% {
    border-width: 0px 400px 100px 400px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #999 transparent;
  }
  100% {
    border-width: 100px 400px 0px 400px;
  }
}

@keyframes animateEnvelope2 {
  0% {
    border-color: transparent #999 #999 #999;
    border-width: 0px 400px 100px 400px;
  }
  100% {
    border-color: white #999 #999 #999;
    border-width: 100px 400px 0px 400px;
  }
}

.base:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent #999 transparent;
  margin-top: -199px;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-name: animateEnvelope;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.base:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent #999 #999 #999;
  border-width: 0px 400px 100px 400px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-name: animateEnvelope2;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="base"></div>
```

It is constructed using two pseudo-elements (`:before` and `:after`). The `:before` produces  a top-facing triangle at first whereas the `:after` is a solid block at the start. First, the `:before` collapses  and then the `:after` animates (after a `animation-delay` which is equal to `animation-duration` on the `:before` element) from being a solid block to a bottom facing triangle.

Ideally using `clip-path` would be the best choice for effects like this but that still has somewhat poor browser support (as it is not fully compatible with IE) and so is not workable if we need cross-browser solution. Using `border` is generally not recommended for cases like this because it is not responsive (unless used with viewport units) but since you've mentioned that the [base element has fixed width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42411226/animating-before-does-not-work-properly#comment71969628_42411226), it should not be a problem for your case.

Comment: I changed it to suit my needs, but that is indeed exactly what I want! Thanks! My edited version: https://jsfiddle.net/qv68L0gg/1/

Comment: You're welcome @Jason. Please consider accepting and/or upvoting the answer if it helped you.

Comment: You're welcome again @Jason and I've approved your suggested edit also as it doesn't change the meaning of the answer :)